# Is there a way to .slice() the response that comes back from a JQuery .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is there any way to slice the response that comes back from the jquery .load() request?

I would like to only insert the first two divs with the class "col-sm-6" that comes back.  I was not sure if I could use the .slice(2) with this.  I am thinking that I can not do this with this .load() and instead need to use another jquery method such as .ajax().  I was trying to avoid this since I am thinking that $this would not be accessible from within the success callback. I apologize in advance if this is overly simple.

```
function loadHtmlIntoDivs () {


    $(".unorderedList").each(function(){
        var ajaxQueryParameter = $(this).attr("data-ajaxQueryParameter");
        var ajaxUrl = "/ajaxPath?ajaxQuery="+ ajaxQueryParameter;

        $(this).find(".specialDiv").load(ajaxUrl);          

    });
}
```

Comment: You can add a selector to your `load` function to only load that element. If you read the manual you would have seen it.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying...I was trying to use "slice" but that is probably not the right way to go.,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add selectors to the [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function to only load does selectors. So you want only the first 2 `.col-sm-6` elements, so you could do:

```
 $(this).find(".specialDiv").load(ajaxUrl + " .col-sm-6:nth-child(-n+2)");
```

Comment: This completely worked!!!! Thank you, thank you, thank you.   I was so focused on trying to figure out a way to use the .slice() that I completely ignored the most obvious answer.